# How to detach logic from controllers and put it to some handler using annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

In our project we already have some necessary controllers and my task is to make it easier. It should work like this: I just put an annotation under a controller and a handler do all its job. What I already have:

```
/**
 * This annotation marks collector methods
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Collect {

}

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Collectors {

    /**
     * An array of subclasses that can load and provide values for
     * generating a ModelMap.
     */
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

I can't find any example how to do it. Controller example:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    private final SchoolService schoolService;

    private final TeacherService teacherService;


    public TestController(SchoolService schoolService, TeacherService teacherService) {
        this.schoolService = schoolService;
        this.teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the static list of users in model and renders it
     * via freemarker template.
     *
     * @param model
     * @return The index view (FTL)
     */
    @Collectors(SchoolCollector.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "freemarker/freemarkertest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
        List<SchoolDTO> schoolList = new ArrayList<SchoolDTO>();
        schoolList = schoolService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("schoolList", schoolList);
        return "freemarkertest";
    }

    /**
     * Add a new School
     *
     * @param schoolDTO
     * @return Redirect back to same /freemarkertest page to display school list, if successful
     */
    @Collectors(SchoolCollector.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "freemarker/freemarkertest/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("schoolDTO") SchoolDTO schoolDTO) {
        if(schoolDTO.getName() != null && !schoolDTO.getName().isEmpty() &&
                schoolDTO.getEnabled() != null) {
            schoolService.save(schoolDTO);
            return "redirect:";
        } else {
            return "redirect:error"; //TODO: create error page
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get list of teachers.
     *
     * @param model
     * @param schoolId
     * @return The index view (FTL)
     */
    @Collectors(SchoolCollector.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "freemarker/teachers/{schoolId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model, @PathVariable Long schoolId) {
        List<TeacherDTO> teachers = teacherService.getAllBySchoolId(schoolId);
        model.addAttribute("teachersList", teachers);
        model.addAttribute("schoolId", schoolId);
        return "teachers";
    }

}
```

Comment: hi, i am just curious if, HandlerInterceptorAdapter was the thing you were looking for, and if not, it would be great to see your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are HandlerInterceptorAdapters. Those have to be defined in your `SpringMvc-servlet.xml`, than those will intercept all your requests.

```
public class CollectorHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod && modelAndView != null) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            if (handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(Collectors.class) == null) {
                return;
            }

            /**
              * Your logic here
              */
        }
    }
}
```

For further reading:

- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor
- https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/

PS: I also want to add, that your code will not work, as you have some "errors" in it... returning Strings instead of objects as an example

Comment: https://github.com/aepfli/springMVCInterception -> is an example of mine, which shows how to "intercept" in different ways, just as a sidenote